# Track input transformation for keras-flavored mlflow models

Tags: keras, mlflow

**TL/DR:** How to track and serve the input transformation for keras-flavored mlflow models?

Neural network training usually involves preprocessing steps in which

- continuous variables are scaled and shifted to have unit width and zero mean,
- categorical variables (integer or string) are transformed to one-hot encoding.

When the model is applied to new data, the scaling weights and the category-to-index association needs to be known.

In keras there are generally two options to perform preprocessing:

- **Option 1:** Using [preprocessing layers](https://keras.io/guides/preprocessing_layers/), or
- **Option 2:** perform the transformation before the training when the dataset is loaded.

With **Option 1**, the transformation is part of the model and will be automatically applied when the network is used and served as a [mlflow model](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html).

My question concerns **Option 2**: What is the recommended way

- to keep track of the input transformation in mlflow for different experiments,
- and how to apply the same transformations when the model is served, e.g. with `mlflow model serve`?